# Orbits under central forces

Tags: classical-mechanics

A particle moves in a plane under a force, towards a fixed centre, proportional to the distance. If the path of the particle has two apsidal distances $a,b\ (a>b)$, then find the equation of the path.

Comment: Try to show what you did it. As I understand, the force is $-k\vec{r}$ with $k > 0$. In that case, you have two uncoupled harmonic oscillators.

Comment: I am stuck in the integration part

Comment: dtheta = du/√(u²-a²)(b²-u²)

Comment: Check [this link about Elliptic Integrals](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2) .

Comment: Can't understand anything on that page.

Comment: Is there any simple way to integrate.

Comment: Try to elaborate your question a little bit. For example, write the equations you want to solve with the boundary conditions included. In that way it will be helpful for people that want to put an answer. It's difficult to say something else with a statement of a few words. On the other hand, $\texttt{MSE-people}$ like to see what you tried about your problem.