# Central force and orbits

Tags: classical-mechanics

A particle moves in a plane under a force, towards a fixed centre, proportional to the distance. If the path of the particle has two apsidal distances $a,b$ $(a>b)$, then find the equation of the path.

I came across this question on MSE. While solving I could only proceed to the step
$$                 h^2(du/dθ^2+u^2)=(k/u^2)+C                  $$
  where $C$ is constant of integration and the force is considered as 
                  $$\mathbf F=-k\mathbf r.$$
I also know that at an apse $du/dθ=0$. How do I proceed further?

---

EDIT: I have found out the pedal equation of the orbit and it seems to be an ellipse. How do I find out in terms of polar coordinates $u(=1/r),θ$? It is required to prove that 
$$       u^2=(sin^2θ)/b^2+(cos^2θ)/a^2    $$
Here's a link to the original question
[Orbits under central forces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938486/orbits-under-central-forces)

Comment: You should link to the original question so people can see the solution you are talking about.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. What is the $h^2$ step and can you formulate your question using the appropriate MathJax.

Comment: The motion under the gravity potential $GMm/r$ has the equation $\ddot{\mathrm r}=-\frac{GM}{r^3}\mathbf r$. Is that also "a force, towards a fixed centre, proportional to the distance"?

Answer (score 0):

The system 
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf r} = -k\mathbf r
$$
that you seem to describe consists of two decoupled harmonic oscillators. It has solutions $x(t)=A\sin(\omega t+\phi_1)$, $y(t)=B\sin(ωt+ϕ_2)$, $ω^2=\frac{k}m$.

If you set $A=a$, $B=b$, $ϕ_1=0$ and $ϕ_2=\frac\pi2$, then you get a horizontal ellipse with main axes with half-lengths $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I do Not know about Decoupled harmonic oscillators. Could you provide me a link where I could study  about it?

Comment: You get $m\ddot x+kx=0$ where you have no $y$ involved and $m\ddot y+ky=0$ where you have no $x$ involved, the two differential equations, even though they belong to a system, can be separated as scalar ODE, the system is decoupled, it decomposes into smaller isolated sub-systems, here the smallest, scalar ones (scalar = 1D).